# Powershell: is there a cmd-let to read and parse graphviz "*.dot" file?

Tags: powershell, graphviz, dot

Dot file is something like this:

```
digraph G {
  "Welcome" -> "To"
  "To" -> "Web"
  "To" -> "GraphViz!"
}
```

Does powershell have a cmd-let helping to read or write a ".dot" file? What structure does it generate from a ".dot" file?

Comment: You explained that the dotfile is a textfile with the given structure. you need graphviz to parse them. Obviously, you can open these files as text files and modify them, but powershell won't "understand" these files magically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but if you don't mind using one of the release candidates of PowerShell version 5, you could parse it with [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn807178.aspx) and a [template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/10/31/convertfrom-string-example-based-text-parsing.aspx)